# Navigation Drawer with ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-vectordrawable

I am learning & developing a small app in Android Studio using Kotlin and have a question about the navigation drawer.
Is it possible to add a vector drawable animation in place of imageview as shown in the picture?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. Like the library used, the code used to produce the current view etc.

Comment: Yes you can add vector drawable

Comment: @VivekGupta, I have a simple vector drawable xml file, but how can I add the code ?